# python array: calculate mean of each row

Tags: python, arrays, mean

I want to calculate the mean of each row in this array, but this code only calculates the first three.
Why is it doing that? How should I change it in order to calculate the remaining two?

```
import numpy as np

mat=np.array([[6 ,2, 9],
[5, 0, 7],
[4 ,7 ,4],
 [2, 2, 4],
 [9, 1, 1]])

print(mat.mean(axis=1))
```

Comment: Nope, calculates all 5. The `axis=1` parameter in your last line is important.

Answer (score 0):

The axis parameter refers to the dimension used in the calculation, axis = 0 means rows, axis = 1 means columns, etc.
Try this and compare with a manual calculation:
print(mat.mean(axis=0))
print(mat.mean(axis=1))

This is the result:
[5.66666667 4.         5.         2.66666667 3.66666667]
[5.2 2.4 5. ]